# Why are canonical modules supported everywhere?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a local CM ring, and $\omega$ a canonical module of $A$. Here are two properties of $\omega$ from Bruns & Herzog:

- $\omega_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a canonical module of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for every $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}A$.
- $\mu_i(\mathfrak{p},\omega)=\delta_{i}^{\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak{p}}$ for every $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}A$, where $\mu$ denotes the Bass number.

These properties seem to imply that $\operatorname{Supp}\omega=\operatorname{Spec}A$. As [Graham Leuschke](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84685/are-maximal-cohen-macaulay-modules-supported-everywhere/84688#84688) pointed out, this is not a property of maximal CM modules. Why, then, are canonical modules supported everywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See (1.7) on page 87 of [*Some basic results on canonical modules*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kyoto-journal-of-mathematics/volume-23/issue-1/Some-basic-results-on-canonical-modules/10.1215/kjm/1250521612.full). For a local CM ring condition (b) there holds.

Comment: I just realized that $\operatorname{Supp}\omega=\operatorname{Spec}A$ can be deduced from the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(\omega,\omega)\simeq A$!

Comment: In general, $\text{Hom}(\omega, \omega)$ is the S2-ification of $A$ if I recall correctly (see the linked paper of Aoyama, or a different paper by the same author).  

Comment: @ Mahdi Majidi-Zolbanin $\operatorname{Ass}\omega=\operatorname{Ass}A$ from (1.7) also follows from the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(\omega,\omega)=A$. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 5):

Just a little more information with regards to your first question.

Canonical modules make sense for any local ring with a dualizing complex (for example, a complete ring).  In that case, I would define the canonical module to be the first nonzero cohomology of the dualizing complex.  If the ring is not Cohen-Macaulay they need not always localize well however (things are fine in a domain regardless).  For example, the canonical module of the ring

$$R = k[[x,y,z]]/\langle x \rangle \cap \langle y, z \rangle$$

is only be supported at one of the minimal primes of $R$.  The dualizing complex behaves better though.

In the non-local setting, even weirder things can happen (even in domains).